# Enable/Disable Html.ActionLink based on a ViewBag value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewbag, actionlink

I have more `ActionLinks` on a `view`, `MVC project`
I need to enable/disable these buttons based on a `ViewBag` value.

I have added this code in the view

```
@{ 
   if (ViewBag.ModifyOS)
   {
      @Html.ActionLink(@Resources.Common.ModifyOSTerms, "ModifyOSTerms", "Document", new { lotId = LotId }, new { @class = "btn btn-success disabled" })
    }
     else
     {
       @Html.ActionLink(@Resources.Common.ModifyOSTerms, "ModifyOSTerms", "Document", new { lotId = LotId }, new { @class = "btn btn-success" })
      }
}
```

This way it is working correct, but I would like a more elegant way to achieve this.
I have tried this way:

```
@{
   string Disabled = "";
   if (ViewBag.ModifyOS)
   {
    Disabled = "disable";
   }   
  }
```

and I have set this `Disabled` to `ActionLink`

```
 @Html.ActionLink(@Resources.Common.ModifyOSTerms, "ModifyOSTerms", "Document", new { lotId = LotId }, new { @class = "btn btn-success" , disabled = "@Disabled" })
```

I have tried this way:

```
@Html.ActionLink(@Resources.Common.ModifyOSTerms, "ModifyOSTerms", "Document", new { lotId = LotId }, new { @class = "btn btn-success" , disabled = "@(ViewBag.ModifyOS)" })
```

But in both cases the button is always disabled.

Comment: The `disabled` attribute is a `boolean` attribute. It the presence of the attribute which determines if its disabled (`disabled="disabled"` or `disabled="true"` or `disabled="anything"` all mean the same)

Comment: Use an `if` block to either disply thr link or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you can handle disabling by adding `disable` class. Why not go with it?

```
string cssClass = "btn btn-success";
if (ViewBag.ModifyOS)
{
    cssClass += " disabled";
}

@Html.ActionLink(@Resources.Common.ModifyOSTerms, "ModifyOSTerms", "Document", new { lotId = LotId }, new { @class = @cssClass })
```